# SQL queries sometimes slow: show profile -> opening table too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I notice that sometimes requests  put a lot of time running being able to go to several seconds.

My DB is almost empty (some tens of recordings scattered on all the tables)
And this problem can affect any request, even of simple “select” on tables with 10-20 recording.
Thus in priori it is not about a problem of greedy specific requests or about concerns of index etc.

I get out hair for several days without finding the problem.

I thus decided to work a little more methodically and I created a small page very simple PHP with the connection to the DB and the execution of 4 simple requests 'see it below). I verify the run time by updating several times the page and I makes also a show profile.

Result of this test I notice that when one of the requests puts several seconds **the problem seems to come of opening tables**

Now from this analysis **I have strictly no idea of what it means exactly and which other test I should make to determine exactly the problem**.

**Example show profile :**

- starting => 0.000007
- Waiting for query cache lock => 0.000003
- checking query cache for query => 0.000026
- checking permissions => 0.000003
- Opening tables => 1.249692
- System lock => 0.000013
- Waiting for query cache lock => 0.000040
- init => 0.000014
- optimizing => 0.000032
- statistics => 0.000041
- preparing => 0.000024
- Waiting for query cache lock => 0.000004
- preparing => 0.000003
- storing result in query cache => 0.000014
- executing => 0.000003
- Sending data => 0.000038
- end => 0.000005
- query end => 0.000004
- closing tables => 0.000012
- freeing items => 0.000055
- logging slow query => 0.000003
- cleaning up => 0.000043

**This is my test file :**

```
try { 

    /* CONNEXION A LA BDD */

$options=array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES '.ENCODAGEBDD);

    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.BD_SERVEUR.';dbname='.BD_NOM.';',      BD_UTILISATEUR, BD_PASSE, $options);


    /* EXECUTION TEST REQUEST 1 */

$debut = getMicrotime();

    $resultat = $bdd->prepare("SELECT m.*, r.role FROM  t_membres AS m   INNER JOIN     t_roles AS r ON (r.id_role = m.role_id)  WHERE m.login_membre = ?");    
    $resultat->execute(array('test'));

    $fin = getMicrotime();
 $time = $fin - $debut;

    print_r("<strong>requete 1 membre : ".$time."<br></strong>");
    echo "<br>";   

    /* EXECUTION TEST REQUEST 2 */  

 $debut = getMicrotime();

    $resultat = $bdd->prepare("SELECT t.id_taxon, t.taxon, t.permalien, t.taxonomie,    t.titre_page, t.desc_longue, t.titre, t.desc_courte, t.nb_blocs, t.image_taxon, t.parent_id AS  idcat, tc.permalien AS permaliencat, tc.titre AS titrecat, tc.taxonomie AS taxonomiecat,    tc.taxon AS taxoncat FROM  t_taxon AS t   LEFT JOIN t_taxon AS tc ON    (tc.id_taxon=t.parent_id)  WHERE t.permalien = '?' AND t.en_ligne = 1");    

    $resultat->execute(array('blog'));

    $fin = getMicrotime();
 $time = $fin - $debut;  

 print_r("<strong>requete 2 taxon : ".$time."<br></strong>");
    echo "<br>";

    /* EXECUTION TEST REQUEST 3 */ 

    $debut = getMicrotime();

    $resultat = $bdd->prepare("SELECT mp.id_mp FROM t_mp AS mp WHERE    mp.id_membre_dest = ? AND mp.statut_dest = 0 LIMIT 0, 1");   
    $resultat->execute(array(2));

    $fin = getMicrotime();
 $time = $fin - $debut;

    print_r("<strong>requete 3 mp : ".$time."<br></strong>");
    echo "<br>";    

    /* EXECUTION REQUETE 4 */

    $debut = getMicrotime();

    $resultat = $bdd->prepare("SELECT b.id_bloc, b.titre, b.image, b.contenu, b.permalien, b.nb_commentaires, b.date_modif, t.permalien AS permaliencat, t.id_taxon as idcat, t.taxon as taxoncat, t.taxonomie as taxonomiecat, t.titre as titrecat FROM  t_bloc AS b   INNER JOIN t_taxon_bloc as tb ON (tb.id_bloc = b.id_bloc) INNER JOIN t_taxon AS t ON (t.id_taxon=tb.id_taxon)  WHERE b.en_ligne = 1 AND b.date_modif <= '2015-07-08 11:24:05' AND tb.id_taxon= ?   ORDER BY tb.id_bloc DESC  LIMIT 0, 3");   
    $resultat->execute(array(1));

    $fin = getMicrotime();
    $time = $fin - $debut;

    print_r("<strong>requete 4 articles : ".$time."<br></strong>");
    echo "<br>";


}catch (PdoException $e) {            
               exit ;        
}
```

PS: I am on OVH mutualized. I use Mysql and the engine Innodb

Sorry about my english, i am french.

### **More détails :**

Thank you gfunk about your interest

Informations :

**1/ EXPLAINS**

```
SELECT m.*, r.role FROM  t_membres AS m   INNER JOIN t_roles AS r ON     (r.id_role = m.role_id)  WHERE m.login_membre = ?
```

> id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows 
>   Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE m const login_membre,role_id login_membre 47 const 1
>
> 1 SIMPLE r const PRIMARY PRIMARY 1 const 1

Explain for

```
SELECT t.id_taxon, t.taxon, t.permalien, t.taxonomie, t.titre_page, t.desc_longue, t.titre, t.desc_courte, t.nb_blocs, t.image_taxon, t.parent_id AS idcat, tc.permalien AS permaliencat, tc.titre AS titrecat, tc.taxonomie AS taxonomiecat, tc.taxon AS taxoncat FROM  t_taxon AS t   LEFT JOIN t_taxon AS tc ON (tc.id_taxon=t.parent_id)  WHERE t.permalien = '?' AND t.en_ligne = 1
```

> id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows 
>   Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE t const idx_permalien idx_permalien 302 const 1
>
> 1 SIMPLE tc const PRIMARY PRIMARY 3 const 1

Explain for

```
SELECT mp.id_mp FROM t_mp AS mp WHERE  mp.id_membre_dest = '?' AND
mp.statut_dest = 0 LIMIT 0, 1
```

> id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows 
>   Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE mp ref id_dest id_dest 5 const,const 1 Using index

Explain for

```
SELECT b.id_bloc, b.titre, b.image, b.contenu, b.permalien, b.nb_commentaires, b.date_modif, t.permalien AS permaliencat, t.id_taxon as idcat, t.taxon as taxoncat, t.taxonomie as taxonomiecat, t.titre as titrecat FROM  t_bloc AS b   INNER JOIN t_taxon_bloc as tb ON (tb.id_bloc = b.id_bloc) INNER JOIN t_taxon AS t ON (t.id_taxon=tb.id_taxon)  WHERE b.en_ligne = 1 AND b.date_modif <= '2015-07-08 11:24:05' AND tb.id_taxon= ?   ORDER BY tb.id_bloc DESC  LIMIT 0, 3"
```

> id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows 
>   Extra
>
> 1 SIMPLE t const PRIMARY PRIMARY 3 const 1 NULL
>
> 1 SIMPLE tb ref PRIMARY,id_bloc PRIMARY 3 const 7 Using where; Using
>   index
>
> 1 SIMPLE b eq_ref PRIMARY,en_ligne,idx_datemodif PRIMARY 3
>   mabdd.tb.id_bloc 1 Using where

**2/ SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `t_mp` (
 `id_mp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_membre_exp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'id  du membre expéditeur, vide lorsqu''il s''agit d''une notification du site',
 `id_membre_dest` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sujet` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `message` text NOT NULL,
 `statut_dest` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:non lu; 1 :lu, 2 : répondu, 3: supprimé, 4 : sauvegardé',
 `statut_exp` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0:non lu; 1 :lu, 2 : répondu, 3: supprimé, 4 : sauvegardé',
 `date_envoi` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `id_mp_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `notification` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 : non notification; 1: notification',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_mp`),
 KEY `idx_date` (`date_envoi`),
 KEY `id_mp_parent` (`id_mp_parent`),
 KEY `id_dest` (`id_membre_dest`,`statut_dest`),
 KEY `id_exp` (`id_membre_exp`,`statut_exp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 


CREATE TABLE `t_membres` (
 `id_membre` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `role_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
 `login_membre` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `password_membre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `email_membre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `date_anniversaire` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
 `cle_activation` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `ip_connexion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `description_membre` text NOT NULL,
 `sexe` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I' COMMENT 'H=Homme, F= Femme, I=Indéterminé',
 `preference_sexe` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'I' COMMENT 'H=Homme, F= Femme, I=Indéterminé',
 `avatar` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `url_membre` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT 'URL du blog ou du Site perso du membre',
 `date_inscr_membre` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-01-01 00:00:00',
 `date_modif_membre` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-01-01 00:00:00' COMMENT 'date de modification de son profil, facebook, url (tous les chmaps pouvant contenir du texte)',
 `date_connexion` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-01-01 00:00:00',
 `notification_mail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 ou 1',
 `accept_mp` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = les membres peuvent le contacter, 0 : aucun membre ne peut le contacter.',
 `statut_membre` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:non validé; 1=actif; 2=demande de suppression',
 `sanction` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 : pas de sanction, 1: banni de communication, 2 : banni du site',
 `nb_jours_actifs` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'nombre de jours ou le mebre s''est connecté au site',
 `points_tx` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'points fidelité totatux',
 `points_actuels` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'points fidelité restants après dépense dans une éventuelle boutique....',
 `mode_vacances` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0: pas en vacances, 1 : en vacances',
 `note_interne` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `profil_en_ligne` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0: hors ligne , 1: en ligne, 2 a modérer',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_membre`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email_membre` (`email_membre`),
 UNIQUE KEY `login_membre` (`login_membre`),
 KEY `date_modif_membre` (`date_modif_membre`),
 KEY `date_connexion` (`date_connexion`),
 KEY `points_tx` (`points_tx`),
 KEY `date_inscr_membre` (`date_inscr_membre`),
 KEY `role_id` (`role_id`),
 KEY `date_anniversaire` (`date_anniversaire`),
 KEY `ip_connexion` (`ip_connexion`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT


CREATE TABLE `t_bloc` (
 `id_bloc` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `titre` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A compléter',
 `nom_bloc` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'nom jeu/site/logiciel...',
 `contenu` text NOT NULL,
 `titre_page` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `desc_courte` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `follow_url` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Affin de pouvoir mettre en nofollow les liens douteux 0=Non;  = oui',
 `image` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `video` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `note` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `champopt1` text NOT NULL,
 `champopt2` text NOT NULL,
 `permalien` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `en_ligne` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0: hors ligne , 1: en ligne, 2 brouilloner',
 `date_crea` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `date_modif` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `nb_commentaires` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nb_jaimes` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nb_jaimespas` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pourcentage_jaimes` mediumint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
 `niveau_classement` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'utiliser pour classer des fiches (jeux, sites...) 0 = bof, 1 : bon, 2 : excellent ou régie ou gros partenaires,  3 : très gros coups de coeur ou gros annonceurs ou très gros partenaires',
 `id_bloc_parent` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Utilisé pour les articles de rubriques annexes (actualité, vidéos etc.)',
 `id_membre_bloc` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'id du membre qui propose l''article. 0 par défaut',
 `commentaires_actifs` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'champ pour pour pouvoir bloquer les commentaires ou non',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_bloc`),
 KEY `en_ligne` (`en_ligne`,`date_modif`,`id_bloc`),
 KEY `idx_datemodif` (`date_modif`,`id_bloc`),
 KEY `id_bloc_parent` (`id_bloc_parent`),
 KEY `niveau_classement` (`niveau_classement`),
 KEY `note` (`note`),
 KEY `id_membre_bloc` (`id_membre_bloc`),
 KEY `nom_bloc` (`nom_bloc`),
 KEY `nb_jaimes` (`nb_jaimes`,`pourcentage_jaimes`),
 KEY `pourcentage_jaimes` (`pourcentage_jaimes`,`nb_jaimes`),
 KEY `permalien` (`permalien`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT 


CREATE TABLE `t_taxon` (
 `id_taxon` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `taxonomie` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'categorie, rubrique, tag...',
 `taxon` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nom du tag court',
 `titre` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Plus de liberté pour le titre',
 `desc_longue` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description présente dans la page du tag',
 `desc_courte` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Meta description',
 `titre_page` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Titre présent sur les navigateurs',
 `permalien` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Utilisé pour l''url rewriting',
 `en_ligne` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'en_ligne, hors ligne, noindex...',
 `image_taxon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `date_ajout` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `date_modif` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `parent_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `nb_blocs` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'utilisé pour le moment uniquement pour le srubriques et les catégories afin d''alléger les requêtes et éviter certains count',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_taxon`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx_taxon` (`taxon`),
 UNIQUE KEY `idx_permalien` (`permalien`),
 KEY `date_ajout` (`date_ajout`),
 KEY `date_modif` (`date_modif`),
 KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
 KEY `taxonomie` (`taxonomie`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

**3/ CMD**

Sorry i don't know how i can run the cmd "iostat -x 1" on my Shared hosting:/

Comment: Can you please provide: 1. EXPLAIN statements on your queries (e.g. "EXPLAIN SELECT m.*, r.r_..."), 2. SHOW CREATE TABLE on your tables (e.g. "SHOW CREATE TABLE t_mp"), and 3. if you're running on linux, run the cmd "iostat -x 1" while you run your script to see if whats happening with the disk I/O.

Comment: Thank you about your interest, i added these information, but i don't know about 3.

Comment: @gfunk Sorry i forgot to add "@gfunk" in my Comment

Comment: Hey. I see no issues with query performance based on your EXPLAIN results. My best guess is that it is an I/O problem - i.e. retreiving data from the disk. If thats the case you will need to look at the machine your MySQL server is running on. However, if either of these text columns have a massive amount of data that could explain it as well: t.desc_longue, b.contenu. My last bit of advice is to download JetProfiler demo, it helps me out when things get too complicated. good luck, sorry i couldn't help more

Comment: @gfunk Hi, thank you. I got an answer from OVH. They are a problem from the machines backups that are saturated. They must chnage them. I hope it's really the problem. It's sure it's not about the size of my data (text coloumn) ;)